# onClick: Load image in a random order of 10px blocks

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, css, fade

jQuery

I was wondering is any has seen any code that can load up an image in 10px blocks or any size pixel blocks.

Think of it like a grid.

```
+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+
```

I want the image to fade in, fading each block in.  Hopefully super fast except in some random order.

Do this on onClick or onHover. Then fade it out off hover or onClick again.

Comment: Nivo slider has this. http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

Comment: @elclanrs: Thanks for the link, I'd have to see if I could adapt it to my needs, but yes - this is similar to what I am looking for http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/2/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick mock up for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/adaz/qeNtt/

Obviously it needs some polishing but it's a good start, I guess :)

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: That is a great start thanks. I want a button to toggle.  onClick fadeIn image "pixel" by "pixel" and onClick fadeOut image "pixel" by "pixel"